# Obscure conditional Java Syntax

Tags: java, syntax, if-statement, conditional-operator

We just found, a colleague and I, a strange compiling syntax with the ***If*** conditional syntax :

```
if (true); {
  foo();
}
```

Is there someone here for explaining to us this strange syntax? Thx.

Comment: if( we_are_at_war ); { launch_all_nukes(); } :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part, `if (true);` is just a do-nothing conditional that ends at the `;`.  The rest is a call to `foo()` inside a new scope block.  You should find that `foo()` is always called.

Answer (score 8):

to me, it looks like an if statement with an empty body, followed by a code block that always executes (and is unrelated to the if statement). For example, does foo also execute here:

```
if (false); {
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This makes no real sense but is syntactically correct. It could also be written as

```
if (true) 
{    
    // do nothing 
}
{   
    foo(); 
}
```

with the {} around foo(); meaning nothing in this case. It would limit the scope of variables defined within the {} if there were variables defined.

```
{
   int i=0;
   System.out.println(i);
}
{
   String i="hello";
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is equvalent to

```
if (true) {};
foo();
```

since the if statemnt is ended after the semicolon and the foo statement just got placed in a block ({})
...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a remain from an old debugging if, or someone was planning to write a condition later but never did it...

I think you can safely remove this if statement, there's absolutely no point in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, syntactically it's a conditional with an empty execution statement (i.e. does nothing) followed by a call to foo() enclosed within scoping brackets. foo() is always executed. In practice, if you found this in a real case and not a programming test I suspect one of the following:

1. It's a misprint, in which case it should be corrected (when you find out what the code should do)
2. It's a deliberately obscure piece of code intended to confuse the reader, in which case it should be fixed (replaced with "foo();") and the perpetrator should be hunted down and reprimanded
3. It was generated by a (poor) automated source code generator, in which case it should be commented to indicate that
4. It's left over from a debugging session, in which case it should be restored to whatever it was before the change was made

Answer (score 0):

That's dead code. The if block is useless.

The equivalent of

```
if(doesn't matter whats here) {}
foo();
```

Comment: doesn't matter what's here? what if it throws an exception? e.g.         `if(Long.parseLong("I am not a long") > 1){} foo();` :-)